# libphp5.so library file is missing in httpd.conf file

Tags: apache

I have a query when I compile Apache 2.2.3

./configure --with-module=php5

make

make install

Apache Successfully  install and working fine but its not load the PHP5 module
"  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so"

Any suggestion how to getrid of this problem

Regards:

Fasih

Comment: Well, what is the error you get? You _did_ take a look at the log files, didn't you? The problem should be noted in apaches error log file in this case.

Comment: i will check and update u

Comment: Dear friend i have done the new installation of apace still same problem and  no error message in log file any suggestions

Comment: Sorry, but that cannot be. Either the php module _is_ loaded, or the loading fails, then there _must_ be a log entry. Which log file did you check? (always assuming that you did not suppress logging by purpose...) Or could it be that the module _is_ loaded, but you do not use it? Why do you say it is _not_ loaded?